# Dynamically Created CommandButtons Not Firing Command

Tags: c#, .net, button, webforms

I'm creating a custom datatype for Umbraco. This datatype simply reads records from a database and renders them in a html table, no repeaters. In each row there are, initially, two buttons, one to edit the record, and one to delete the record.

On clicking edit, the row is put into edit mode where textboxes are used in place of literals, and instead of buttons being "Edit" and "Delete", the are "Save" and "Cancel".
Clicking either of these buttons does not seem to work. The command they should be firing is not firing.

I've read about having to create these buttons before page load, which i do. I have a List for each type (Save, Cancel). That is generated on Init, ids are based on the ids of the records. And the commands and command arguments are assigned here too.

However, the commands still do not seem to fire.

**Code**

```
public class ProductManagerDataEditor : System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel, umbraco.interfaces.IDataEditor
{
    private umbraco.interfaces.IData _data;

    //Properties
    private List<Record> Records { get; set; }
    private int EditRecordID = 0;

    //Editor Controls
    TextBox tb_EditName;
    TextBox tb_EditPrice;
    Button btn_Add;
    List<Button> EditButtons;
    List<Button> DeleteButtons;
    List<Button> SaveButtons;
    List<Button> CancelButtons;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// Reads in curent data along with configuration settings for this data type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Data"></param>
    /// <param name="Configuration"></param>
    public ProductManagerDataEditor(umbraco.interfaces.IData Data, SortedList<String, String> Configuration)
    {
        _data = Data;
    }

    public virtual bool TreatAsRichTextEditor
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
    public bool ShowLabel
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    public Control Editor { get { return this; } }
    public void Save()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Init Method
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Load Method
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
            LoadRecords();
        GenerateControls();
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
        RenderTableContents(writer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the buttons to be used
    /// </summary>
    protected void GenerateControls()
    {
        SaveButtons = new List<Button>();
        CancelButtons = new List<Button>();
        DeleteButtons = new List<Button>();
        EditButtons = new List<Button>();

        //Other Buttons
        foreach (Record r in Records)
        {
            //Save Button
            Button btn_Save = new Button();
            btn_Save.CssClass = "btn-save";
            btn_Save.ID = "btnSave_" + r.ID;
            btn_Save.Text = "Save";
            btn_Save.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Save);
            btn_Save.CommandArgument = r.ID.ToString();

            //Cancel Edting Button
            Button btn_Cancel = new Button();
            btn_Cancel.CssClass = "btn-cancel";
            btn_Cancel.ID = "btnCancel";
            btn_Cancel.Text = "Cancel";
            btn_Cancel.Click += new EventHandler(CancelEdit);

            //Delete Button
            Button btn_Del = new Button();
            btn_Del.CssClass = "btn-delete";
            btn_Del.ID = "btnDelete_" + r.ID;
            btn_Del.Text = "Delete";
            btn_Del.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Delete);
            btn_Del.CommandArgument = r.ID.ToString();

            //Edit Button
            Button btn_Edit = new Button();
            btn_Edit.CssClass = "btn-edit";
            btn_Edit.ID = "btnEdit_" + r.ID;
            btn_Edit.Text = "Edit";
            btn_Edit.Command += new CommandEventHandler(EditRecord);
            btn_Edit.CommandArgument = r.ID.ToString();

            SaveButtons.Add(btn_Save);
            CancelButtons.Add(btn_Cancel);
            DeleteButtons.Add(btn_Del);
            EditButtons.Add(btn_Edit);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the records from the database
    /// </summary>
    protected void LoadRecords()
    {
        Records = //Loaded from db...
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Renders The Table of Records
    /// </summary>
    protected void RenderTableContents(HtmlTextWriter w)
    {
        bool editMode = false;

        w.Write("<table class='product-manager' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3px'>");
        w.Write("<tr class='head'>");
        w.Write("<th>Name</th>");
        w.Write("<th>Price</th>");
        w.Write("<th></th>");
        w.Write("<th></th>");
        w.Write("</tr>");

        int buttonIndex = 0;
        foreach (Record r in Records)
        {
            //If editing this record, display text boxes
            if (EditRecordID == r.ID)
            {
                editMode = true;

                tb_EditName = new TextBox { Text = r.Name };
                tb_EditPrice = new TextBox { Text = r.Price.ToString() };

                w.Write("<tr>");
                    w.Write("<td>");
                    tb_EditName.RenderControl(w);
                    w.Write("</td>");
                    w.Write("<td>");
                    tb_EditPrice.RenderControl(w);
                    w.Write("</td>");
                    w.Write("<td>");
                    SaveButtons[buttonIndex].RenderControl(w);
                    w.Write("</td>");
                    w.Write("<td>");
                    CancelButtons[buttonIndex].RenderControl(w);
                    w.Write("</td>");
                w.Write("</tr>");
            }
            //Not in edit mode
            else
            {
                w.Write("<tr>");
                    w.Write("<td>" + t.Name + "</td>");
                    w.Write("<td>&pound;" + t.Price + "</td>");
                    w.Write("<td>");
                    EditButtons[buttonIndex].RenderControl(w);
                    w.Write("</td>");
                    w.Write("<td>");
                    DeleteButtons[buttonIndex].RenderControl(w);
                    w.Write("</td>");
                w.Write("</tr>");
            }
            buttonIndex++;
        }

        w.Write("</table>");
    }


    #region Events
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the id of the row to edit
    /// </summary>
    protected void EditRecord(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        EditRecordID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cancels editing mode
    /// </summary>
    protected void CancelEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditRecordID = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes Selected Record
    /// </summary>
    protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates Record Details
    /// </summary>
    protected void Save(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
       //Update the Record
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: You can create them even in the `Load` event. Your code is creating them but that's not enough. You need to put them on page. Do you do that in `RenderTable`? Can you put this code too?

Comment: Hi Amiram, I have updated my question to contain the code that renders the table.

Comment: As seen here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.contenttemplatecontainer you need to create them in `Load` event. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Amiram. I dont have access to a Page_Load() as this is a control, but I do have access to an OnLoad method. I moved the "GenerateControls()" to that but still no "Save" or "Cancel" events fire. Perhaps I need to do something specific for Umbraco afterall. But I am just creating a control that inherits from UpdatePanel.

Comment: Do you inherit `UpdatePanel`? What is the `pnl_Table` variable? I don't think inheritance is what you need here. Looks like you're doing something very specific. What not use a `UserControl`?

Comment: The control inherits from System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel, and umbraco.interfaces.IDataEditor. The pnl_Table is an Update panel that stores the table. There is a method of creating umbraco datatypes through usercontrols, which might work better then, I just thought I should be able to get these events to fire.

Comment: So you have two `UpdatePanels`? You inherit from one and you have another one in it? Also, you're changing the asp.net page life cycle. You're not supposed to render things in `OnInit`.

Comment: Yeah, I shall alter things around and report back. Ill remove pnl_Table and instead add controls to "this" and then move the rendering to the OnLoad method.

Comment: Rendering should be in the `Render` method

Comment: I've made the changes as above, and moved the rendering into the Render method. Now when I click edit, the event isnt called, the control is just rendered again and I cant get into edit mode. After some more testing, none of the buttons are working. "Add", "Edit" and "Delete" used to work.

Comment: Edit your question with all your code. Currently it's hard to understand what exactly you tries and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and apparently the problematic code was the rendering. The `UpdatePanel` didn't treat the buttons as triggers at all.

The solution is to add the controls to the panel within an `asp:Table` and let the `UpdatePanel` do the rendering, so skip the rendering code.

This is what you need to change (this is just for the edit button but you can add code for all):

```
protected void GenerateControls()
{
    var table = new Table();
    var headerRow = new TableHeaderRow();
    var headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Name";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Price";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    table.Rows.Add(headerRow);

    //Other Buttons
    foreach (Record r in Records)
    {
        var row = new TableRow();

        var cell = new TableCell();
        //Edit Button
        Button btn_Edit = new Button();
        btn_Edit.CssClass = "btn-edit";
        btn_Edit.ID = "btnEdit_" + r.ID;
        btn_Edit.Text = "Edit";
        btn_Edit.Command += new CommandEventHandler(EditRecord);
        btn_Edit.CommandArgument = r.ID.ToString();
        cell.Controls.Add(btn_Edit);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

BTW, this looks like a grid. Why don't you use a `GridView` or a `ListView`?

Comment: Thanks Amiram! I've tried the code and have the table rendering. The Edit event is getting fired, and the EditRecordID is being set. However, the table is not being re-rendered with one of the rows in edit mode. Do I need to manually render?
I avoided gridview/listview as I wasnt sure how to go about creating these programatically and setting itemtemplates. It seems DataList would be ideal!

Comment: I think `ListView` or `GridView` would be the best. When you add controls programmatically (can't you add them in template in aspx?), you need to add them for each row in `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: Because of the way these UmbracoDataTypes are created, I have to do it programatically. Although there is another method where I could perhaps use an ascx which is the route i may have to take, if I cant get this to reload with a row in edit mode.

Comment: Hi Amiram, I couldnt get to the bottom of the issue with the buttons not working so i moved on to use an ascx file which was much much easier! Thanks for your time and effort though :)